# What to do if sonarqube fails due to negative SQALE density value

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

We have upgraded to SonarQube 5.1 and analyze our huge multi-module project with it using Maven. While for several runs the analysis was successful, since some days we now get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project jahia-dev-root: The SQALE density value should be between 0 and 1.7976931348623157E308 and got -0.004 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project jahia-dev-root: The SQALE density value should be between 0 and 1.7976931348623157E308 and got -0.004
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The SQALE density value should be between 0 and 1.7976931348623157E308 and got -0.004
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: The SQALE density value should be between 0 and 1.7976931348623157E308 and got -0.004
```

From the log the last sub-module analyzed was a webapp without java files, but just groovy, jsp, javascript and xml files. Anyone has an idea, if there is a workaround or how to proceed solving that problem?
We have upgraded plugins to Java 3.3, Groovy 1.1.1, XML 1.3 last week. Could it be related?

**UPDATE 14.07.2015:** I found that switching to Default XML Profile with 0 rules activated solved the problem. Before I had the following XML rules active:

- Newlines should follow each element
- Source code should be indented consistently
- Tabulation characters should not be used

I still don't know why activating these XML rules runs into that exception.

Comment: This issue is probably related to the last release of the XML plugin 1.3 where SQALE remediation cost definition and computation for rules have been added. It seems that the problem comes from a SQALE value which  is wrongly set. A workaround would be indeed to deactivate the "buggy" rule but from the piece of log I cannot tell which one it is. Also I was not able to reproduce the problem. Could you provide the full debug log of the analysis and/or a project reproducer please ?

Comment: Hello Linda, thanks for your reply. It happens on an open source component which is also analyzed by your public SonarQube instance: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/components/index?id=209738

Comment: thank you for the information and the delayed answer. The analysis on nemo is successful with SonarQube version 5.1 and XML Plugin version 1.3. To make further investigation could you please provide the following information: - the remediation cost of the 3 activated rules - their configuration (value of the their parameters) - have you set a custom value for the property `sonar.technicalDebt.developmentCost`, in SQALE setting ? - finally the list of the plugin installed in the concerned SonarQube instance

Comment: I am receiving the same error. I am not sure which plug-in is causing this error though. The error I am receiving is: `The SQALE density value should be between 0 and 1.7976931348623157E308 and got -0.016666666666666666 -> [Help 1]
` I am trying to run sonar from Maven with a specific Java profile. I am using SonarQube 4.5.5.